# Ruby on Rails installation on Lion (again), whats wrong here:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, gcc, installation

I know this has been asked before and Ive tried lots of stuff but I cant get this to work.

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

or

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

gives:

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/usr/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/usr/.rvm/src
Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/usr/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/usr/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/usr/.rvm/log/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/usr/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/usr/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/usr/.rvm/log/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/usr/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/usr/.rvm/log/yaml/make.log
```

And the three log files are:

Extract.log:

```
[2012-04-22 18:41:07] tar xmzf /Users/usr/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/usr/.rvm/src 
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-reformatter-alt.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-deconstructor.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
…
100 rows like this
…
yaml-0.1.4/win32/config.h: Can't unlink already-existing object
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Configure.log:

```
[2012-04-22 20:12:18]  ./configure --prefix="/Users/usr/.rvm/usr"  --with-gcc=clang 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-gcc
./configure: line 2215: confdefs.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 2219: confdefs.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 2223: confdefs.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 2227: confdefs.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 2231: confdefs.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 2235: confdefs.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 2239: confdefs.h: Permission denied
checking for a BSD-compatible install... ./configure: line 2443: conftest.one: Permission denied
./configure: line 2444: conftest.two: Permission denied
mkdir: conftest.dir: Permission denied
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
config/install-sh -c
checking whether build environment is sane... ./configure: line 2492: conftest.file Permission denied
configure: error: ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken
alias in your environment
configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
```

make.log:

```
[2012-04-22 20:44:29] make 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

ruby -v gives *Not updated as you can see:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

gcc -v gives:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
```

xcodebuild -version gives:

```
Xcode 4.3.2
Build version 4E2002
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Wasnt this hard to get rails up and running a couple of years ago..

Comment: Issues like this led me to switch to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). Just for what it's worth.

Comment: I followed this guide [link](http://samsoff.es/posts/how-to-install-ruby-193) and it installed OK but ruby -v still gives the old version.  Installing ruby is not that user friendly :)

Comment: OK this line: `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` switches the ruby version. After I type that and then `ruby -v` I get `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]` - BUT - after I restart the terminal and type `ruby -v` again its back to `1.8.7`? What can I do to make it permanent? – mdc just now edit

Comment: You need to set that in your .bash_profile or .zshenv, whatever environment file your terminal uses.

Comment: I added it to my bash_login file...didnt have the other ones. I had tried to add it to my .profile file but that didnt work. Thanks. Finally solved.

Comment: Updated with the answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I followed [this guide](http://samsoff.es/posts/how-to-install-ruby-193) and then added

```
"$(rbenv init -)"
```

to my bash_login file.